# Is it possible to use JSONPath or XPath to get a query string?

Tags: rest, xpath, oauth, jsonpath, insomnia

I'm currently using Insomnia App to create some requests and one of my API responses I get a JSON with "redirect_uri" field and the value is actually a URL.

I need to get `only the code parameter`, so the JSONPath or XPath needs to return `8748d39f-1d4f-311f-92c6-4b279db1b317` in the following example:

```
{
  "redirect_uri": "http://www.google.com?state=string&code=8748d39f-1d4f-311f-92c6-4b279db1b317"
}
```

Value to return: `8748d39f-1d4f-311f-92c6-4b279db1b317`

Is it possible with JSONPath or XPath?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with this somewhat convoluted xpath expression:

```
substring-before(substring-after('{
  "redirect_uri": "http://www.google.com?state=string&code=8748d39f-1d4f-311f-92c6-4b279db1b317"
}',
'code='),'"')
```

Comment: Thanks. That works. I'll adapt it to my Insomnia request